# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'display'

Tags: python-3.x

[image]
why is this giving `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'display'` even when `display` module is present in `dir()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're doing it wrong.
Use below code to import.

```
from IPython.display import display_png as dp
```

**EDIT**

You can not directly call submodules using import statement.
You have to first call top module.

For eg.

```
from sklearn import tree
```

This will import tree module from sklearn but after importing this you try to call `tree`

```
import tree
```

You will get an error as

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tree'
```